# Gitlab CI npm cannot resolve module

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, continuous-integration, nuxt.js

Totally new to Gitlab and CI in general, so apologies for the lack of understanding. I have a repo, which is NuxtJS based, with a Dockerfile. The end goal of the pipeline is to build and push this repo to my docker account. The Dockerfile is relatively straight forward, containing an `npm install` and `npm run build`. I'm using a custom docker image as my runner, based on `docker:20.10.17-dind-alpine3.16` with ansible, terraform and kubectl installed.

When building the project's docker image on my local machine, I receive no issues, however in gitlab, when running the `npm run build` command, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/vue-confirm-dialog' in '/usr/src/nuxt-app/plugins'
```

Here is my yml file:

```yaml
stages:
  - docker

docker:
  stage: docker
  image: <my-runner-image>
  services:
  - "docker:dind"
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $DOCKER_REGISTRY_USER -p $DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
  script:
    - docker build -t <my-repo> .
    - docker push <my-repo>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

--EDIT--
As requested, here is the project's Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.15

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: I think better to add the dockerfile content as well so we can point out if there is any issue in that.

Comment: Side node: you can (and should) remove `RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app` (it is unneeded because `WORKDIR /path` already amounts to running `mkdir -p /path && cd /path`)

Comment: Is `vue-confirm-dialog` installed? (is it in your lockfile?)

Comment: I'm going to close this, was resolved by manually adding a step to my docker file to install the package separately. Kind of annoying, but it works